# Daylight savings time causing .net app to consume 100% cpu

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, dst

Ok, so daylight savings time came and went in Denmark this weekend. And it was anything but uneventful. We have a webscraping app that runs on a server farm. At any given point in time, we are running 2-6000 instances of this app. Normally this works quite fine.

We do developments to this app over time and release new stuff. So while most of the existing codebase has been through this process several times without incident, some of it is new.

When the clocks changed on sunday, we had 5.500 instances running. Of those ~100 of them decided to stop doing what the normally do, and instead spend 100% cputime on a single core until terminated.

So my question is as following: 
Have anyone out there experienced something like this while using the .net4.0 framework? I know it's callous to "just" look outside our own scrapheap of code for answers. We are doing an effort in trying to narrow down where the code broke. So this is mainly a matter of looking in both directions for causes.

Comment: Is any of those 100 instances still running? You could attached a debugger to the process, pause it, and take a look at the stack trace to try to find where the problem is.

Comment: It's properly a scheduling job where you convert GMT/UTC and get an off by one due to DST causing an endless loop.

Comment: All the instances have been killed. Since they were disrupting production, someone went through and killed them very thoroughly.

There are no scheduling jobs, nor any gmt/utc conversions. We previously had a bug where we would sleep until a given time came around, but that caused the process to consume near-0 cpu, instead of 100% cpu

Answer (score 1):

It's not likely this was caused by the .NET Framework itself.

This is just a guess, but somewhere in your application, you probably have some code that uses `DateTime.Now`.  For example:

```
DateTime then = DateTime.Now;
// ... do some work ...
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan duration = now - then;
```

Over a DST change, the resulting duration could have an extra hour in the spring, or go negative by up to an hour in the fall.

This by itself won't cause a CPU to hit 100%, but perhaps you are doing something with the results that would.  I would look closely at any loop exit conditions in your application that involve timing.  Example:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
while (DateTime.Now - start < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
{
  // do something
}
```

That example could potentially run for an extra hour in the fall, if it fires at just the right time.  I'm struggling to think of a common condition where an extra hour in the spring would go into an endless loop.  The fall case is much more common.  Still, you should check.

BTW - you certainly should *not* do what I showed above.  Both examples would be better served by [the `Stopwatch` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

Additional reading: [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)